# How to write junit for evaluations in <on-render> tag in spring webflow 2?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-webflow, spring-webflow-2

How can I write the junit for the below webflow:

```
<view-state id="Mydetails" view="checkdetails" model="customerBean">
    <on-entry>
        <set name="flowScope.site" value="Service.getServiceAddress()" />
    </on-entry>
    <on-render>
        <evaluate expression="customer.getdetails(custId)"
            result="flowScope.Details" />
    </on-render>
</view-state>
```

For the evaluation expression in  tag, is it possible to unit test this?

Comment: Did you ever find out how to do this? I'm trying to do exactly the same thing